# Android:Is there a better way to insert and/or update a database entry?

Tags: database, android, insert

I have a database containing a userId and a note. The user doesn't know if there already is a note in the DB so they write one and click the 'Submit' button. I want to insert this note if there is no note for the userId or update that userId's already existing note:

```
notesDb.open();
boolean updateResult = notesDb.updateMessage(
        userId,
        details_notes_input.getText().toString());

if(updateResult == true) {
    Log.d("databaseTester", "Updated entry into table");
} else {
    Log.d("databaseTester", "FAILED to update entry into table");
    long insertResult = notesDb.insertMessage(
            userId,
            details_notes_input.getText().toString());
    if(insertResult == -1){
        Log.d("databaseTester", "Failed to insert entry into table");
    } else {
        Log.d("databaseTester", "Inserted entry into table");
    }   
}
notesDb.close();
```

So, I'm pretty much attempting to 'update' an entry and if I fail then I attempt to 'insert' it. I don't know SQL very well, but I would think there would be a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you could use sqlite's [REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html) to solve this problem, using [`SQLiteDatabase.replace()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)).

Comment: It didn't work for me. I tried _getHelper().getWritableDatabase().replace(TABLE_NAME, null, values);_ Any suggestions?

Comment: You can achieve this functionality through `ContentProvider` by using passing an extra parameter in your `ContentValues`. I wrote a blog post about it here: [SQLite INSERT OR REPLACE through ContentProvider | Buzzing Android](http://www.buzzingandroid.com/2013/01/sqlite-insert-or-replace-through-contentprovider/)

Answer (score 1):

You can catch a constraint exception launched in case of previous ID existence and then update.

```
try {
    db.insertOrThrow("sometable", null, cv);
} catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
    db.update("sometable", cv,"sometable_uid =" + id, null);
}
```

Comment: Using exceptions to manage control flow in this way is probably not a good idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/729404/504611.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

result = db.insertWithOnConflict("tablename ", null, cv, -1);